# Spark Structured Streaming MemoryStream + Row + Encoders issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run some tests on my local machine with spark structured streaming.

In batch mode here is the Row that i am dealing with:

```
val recordSchema = StructType(List(StructField("Record", MapType(StringType, StringType), false)))
val rows         = List(
    Row(
      Map("ID" -> "1",
        "STRUCTUREID" -> "MFCD00869853",
        "MOLFILE" -> "The MOL Data",
        "MOLWEIGHT" -> "803.482",
        "FORMULA" -> "C44H69NO12",
        "NAME" -> "Tacrolimus",
        "HASH" -> "52b966c551cfe0fa7d526bac16abcb7be8b8867d",
        "SMILES" -> """[H][C@]12O[C@](O)([C@H](C)C[C@@H]1OC)""",
        "METABOLISM" -> "The metabolism 500"
       )),
    Row(
      Map("ID" -> "2",
        "STRUCTUREID" -> "MFCD00869854",
        "MOLFILE" -> "The MOL Data",
        "MOLWEIGHT" -> "603.482",
        "FORMULA" -> "",
        "NAME" -> "Tacrolimus2",
        "HASH" -> "52b966c551cfe0fa7d526bac16abcb7be8b8867d",
        "SMILES" -> """[H][C@]12O[C@](O)([C@H](C)C[C@@H]1OC)""",
        "METABOLISM" -> "The metabolism 500"
      ))
  )
val df  = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows), recordSchema)
```

Working with that in Batch more works as a charm, no issue.

Now I'm try to move in streaming mode using MemoryStream for testing. I added the following:

> ```
> implicit val ctx = spark.sqlContext
> val intsInput = MemoryStream[Row]
> ```

But the compiler complain with the as follows:

> **No implicits found for parameter evidence$1: Encoder[Row]**

Hence, my question: What should I do here to get that working

Also i saw that if I add the following import the error goes away:

> import spark.implicits._

Actually, I now get the following warning instead of an error

> Ambiguous implicits for parameter evidence$1: Encoder[Row]

I do not understand the encoder mechanism well and would appreciate if someone could explain to me how not to use those implicits. The reason being that I red the following in a book when it comes to the creation of DataFrame from Rows.

Recommended appraoch:

```
val myManualSchema = new StructType(Array(
  new StructField("some", StringType, true),
  new StructField("col", StringType, true),
  new StructField("names", LongType, false)))
val myRows = Seq(Row("Hello", null, 1L))
val myRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(myRows)
val myDf = spark.createDataFrame(myRDD, myManualSchema)
myDf.show()
```

And then the author goes on with this:

> In Scala, we can also take advantage of Spark’s implicits in the
>   console (and if you import them in your JAR code) by running toDF on a
>   Seq type. This does not play well with null types, so it’s not
>   necessarily recommended for production use cases.

```
val myDF = Seq(("Hello", 2, 1L)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

If someone could take the time to explain what is happening in my scenario when i use the implicit, and if it is rather safe to do so, or else is there a way to do it more explicitly without importing the implicit.

Finally, if someone could point me to a good doc around Encoder and Spark Type mapping that would be great.

**EDIT1**

I finally got it to work with

```
  implicit val ctx = spark.sqlContext
  import spark.implicits._
  val rows = MemoryStream[Map[String,String]]
  val df = rows.toDF()
```

Although my problem here is that i am not confident about what I am doing. It seems to me that it is like in some situation I need to create a DataSet to be able to convert it in an DF[ROW] with toDF conversion. I understood that working with DS is typeSafe but slower than with DF. So why this intermediary with DataSet? This is not the first time that i see that in Spark Structured Streaming. Again if someone could help me with those, that would be great.

Comment: Since Spark 2.0, a `Dataframe` is just a type alias for `Dataset[Row]`. You lose type-safety by using the `Row` object since it has no constraints of the data it contains. So, should you use `Dataset[T]` over a `Dataset[Row]`? We can use [this great blog-post from Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) as a guideline: "If you want higher degree of type-safety at compile time, want typed JVM objects, take advantage of Catalyst optimization, and benefit from Tungsten’s efficient code generation, use Dataset."

Answer (score 8):

I encourage you to use Scala's `case classes` for data modeling.

```scala
final case class Product(name: String, catalogNumber: String, cas: String, formula: String, weight: Double, mld: String)
```

Now you can have a `List` of `Product` in memory:

```scala
  val inMemoryRecords: List[Product] = List(
    Product("Cyclohexanecarboxylic acid", " D19706", "1148027-03-5", "C(11)H(13)Cl(2)NO(5)", 310.131, "MFCD11226417"),
    Product("Tacrolimus", "G51159", "104987-11-3", "C(44)H(69)NO(12)", 804.018, "MFCD00869853"),
    Product("Methanol", "T57494", "173310-45-7", "C(8)H(8)Cl(2)O", 191.055, "MFCD27756662")
  )
```

The [structured streaming API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) makes it easy to reason about stream processing by using the widely known `Dataset[T]` abstraction. Roughly speaking, you just have to worry about three things:

- [Source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources): a source can generate an input data stream which we can represent as a `Dataset[Input]`. Every new data item `Input` that arrives is going to be appended into this unbounded dataset. You can manipulate the data as you wish (e.g. `Dataset[Input]` => `Dataset[Output]`).
- [StreamingQueries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#starting-streaming-queries) and [Sink](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks): a query generates a result table that's updated from the Source every trigger interval. Changes are written into external storage called a Sink.
- [Output modes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes): there are different modes on which you can write data into the Sink: complete mode, append mode, and update mode.

Let's assume that you want to know the products that contain a molecular weight bigger than 200 units.

As you said, using the batch API is fairly simple and straight-forward:

```scala
// Create an static dataset using the in-memory data
val staticData: Dataset[Product] = spark.createDataset(inMemoryRecords)

// Processing...
val result: Dataset[Product] = staticData.filter(_.weight > 200)

// Print results!
result.show()
```

When using the Streaming API you just need to define a `source` and a `sink` as an extra step. In this example, we can use the `MemoryStream` and the `console` sink to print out the results.

```scala
// Create an streaming dataset using the in-memory data (memory source)
val productSource = MemoryStream[Product]
productSource.addData(inMemoryRecords)

val streamingData: Dataset[Product] = productSource.toDS()

// Processing...
val result: Dataset[Product] = streamingData.filter(_.weight > 200)

// Print results by using the console sink. 
val query: StreamingQuery = result.writeStream.format("console").start()

// Stop streaming
query.awaitTermination(timeoutMs=5000)
query.stop()
```

Note that the `staticData` and the `streamingData` have the exact type signature (i.e., `Dataset[Product]`). This allows us to apply the same processing steps regardless of using the Batch or Streaming API. You can also think of implementing a generic method `def processing[In, Out](inputData: Dataset[In]): Dataset[Out] = ???` to avoid repeating yourself in both approaches.

Complete code example:

```scala
object ExMemoryStream extends App {

  // Boilerplate code...
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("ExMemoryStreaming")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  import spark.implicits._
  implicit val sqlContext: SQLContext = spark.sqlContext

  // Define your data models 
  final case class Product(name: String, catalogNumber: String, cas: String, formula: String, weight: Double, mld: String)

  // Create some in-memory instances
  val inMemoryRecords: List[Product] = List(
    Product("Cyclohexanecarboxylic acid", " D19706", "1148027-03-5", "C(11)H(13)Cl(2)NO(5)", 310.131, "MFCD11226417"),
    Product("Tacrolimus", "G51159", "104987-11-3", "C(44)H(69)NO(12)", 804.018, "MFCD00869853"),
    Product("Methanol", "T57494", "173310-45-7", "C(8)H(8)Cl(2)O", 191.055, "MFCD27756662")
  )

  // Defining processing step
  def processing(inputData: Dataset[Product]): Dataset[Product] =
    inputData.filter(_.weight > 200)

  // STATIC DATASET
  val datasetStatic: Dataset[Product] = spark.createDataset(inMemoryRecords)

  println("This is the static dataset:")
  processing(datasetStatic).show()

  // STREAMING DATASET
  val productSource = MemoryStream[Product]
  productSource.addData(inMemoryRecords)

  val datasetStreaming: Dataset[Product] = productSource.toDS()

  println("This is the streaming dataset:")
  val query: StreamingQuery = processing(datasetStreaming).writeStream.format("console").start()
  query.awaitTermination(timeoutMs=5000)
  
  // Stop query and close Spark
  query.stop()
  spark.close()

}
```